# Python create a lists from a pandas dataframe of numbers that are repeated down the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns. As you can see in row 0 we have a 1 and a 2 the first list.  Column_1 does not have any rows with 2 so that would be the first list.  In row 1 you have 4 and 6, 6 is in row 3 with 9, 9 is on line 4 with 15 and in row 6 we have 15 and 14, so the list would be [4,6,9,15,14].  So forth and so on.

```
df
   Column_1   Column_2
0  1          2
1  4          6
2  5          8
3  6          9
4  9          15
5  11         22
6  15         14
```

I am looking to create a list of lists like the following from the df above:

```
list1
[[1,2], [4,6,9,15,14], [5,8], [11,22]]
```

Comment: what happens if you have duplicates in `Column_1`? or is that not possible?

Comment: There will be no duplicates in Column_1  thanks @Buckeye14Guy

Comment: check out `networkx` package and connected components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, this is a connected component problem. So check out [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/). Here's a solution:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(a,b) for a,b in zip(df['Column_1'], df['Column_2'])])
list(nx.connected_components(G))
```

output:

```
[{1, 2}, {4, 6, 9, 14, 15}, {5, 8}, {11, 22}]
```

(not list of list, but I assume that will do)

Comment: My thoughts exactly - was just trying this out in an interpreter myself to verify... but you beat me to it :)

Comment: I'd cut out the list-comp and unpacking, and just go straight for `G.add_edges_from(zip(df['Column_1'], df['Column_2']))` though

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, didn't know that it would work.

Comment: and here I am with a recursive function. smh. I should look into this package too

Comment: @QuangHoang or even better, as long the OP can guarantee it's only 2 columns, then access the underlying numpy array structure behind the DF, eg: `G.add_edges_from(df.values)`

Comment: @QuangHoang is it possible to keep the ordering of the edge? i.e. return a list instead of a set to preserve that vertex insertion order?